# How to save nested Backbone models with Django REST Framework

Tags: javascript, python, django, backbone.js, django-rest-framework

I am trying to rapid-fire save a series of items related by foreign keys. After the parent item is saved, I then use the returned id of the parent item when creating the child item.

This works once or twice, but on the second or third time, I get the message:

```js
{"parent_id":["Invalid pk \"5063\" - object does not exist."]}
```

I have verified that:

- The ID being sent to create the related item is in fact the same one that was returned in the `done()` after saving the parent item
- If I add in a delay before the child item is created, I can check in the database and verify that the parent item was indeed created and saved to the database
- If I add in a long enough delay before the child item is created (~15 s), no error is produced

Since the Backbone.js front-end seems to be sending valid POST requests, and the items are being written to the database correctly right away, I presume that this is a Django problem.

## Backbone.js code

```js
var i = 0;

function createNew() {
    var parent = ParentObjects.add({name: "New Parent Item"});
    parent.save().done(function(var attributes, stuff, stuff) {
        var id = attributes.id;
        var child = ChildObjects.add({name: "New Child Item", parent_id: id});
        child.save().done(function() {
            i++;
            if (i < 10) {
                createNew();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

## Django Rest Framework code

```
class Parent(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Child(Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name="children")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ParentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent

class ChildSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    parent_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        source='parent',
        queryset=Parent.objects.all(),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        exclude = ('parent', )

class ChildViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Child.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChildSerializer

class ParentViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Parent.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer
```

The database is Postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It looks like* a race-condition is happening where the first request succeeded but is still not yet into the database, *possibly* just in cache in a thread for this request. Then a subsequent call arrives, another thread is created to handle it but the parent *isn't yet really* in the database so it fails.

## How to save nested models with Backbone?

The rule of thumb with Backbone is **don't loop requests to the API one after the other.**

Instead, send the whole object to the API. **Foreign key is a relational database concept** and you should try to avoid doing the database/backend job on the frontend.

For example, the parent's `attributes` could be used to created both the parent and its children at the same time:

```js
ParentObjects.create({
    name: "New Parent Item",
    children: [
        { name: "New Child Item" }
    ]
});
```

The backend should return:

```
{
    id: "23",
    name: "New Parent Item",
    children: [
        { id: "35", name: "New Child Item", parent: "23" }
    ]
}
```

## How to save nested models with Django REST Framework (DRF)?

Since version 3, DRF offers [writable nested representation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations) so it works almost out-of-the-box with the Backbone example above. You only need to provide a serializer for the child model field and override the `create` method.

Here's an example from the doc with a simple relation `User <- Profile`:

> ```
> class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
>     profile = ProfileSerializer()
>
>     class Meta:
>         model = User
>         fields = ('username', 'email', 'profile')
>
>     def create(self, validated_data):
>         profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
>         user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
>         Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
>         return user
> ```

Comment: Thanks! That seems like a good alternative solution. I'm still confused as to why exactly this is happening, because when I add a 5 second delay before the Child is saved, and check the Parent table in the database, the new Parent is there, but saving the Child still fails as if no such Parent existed.

Comment: @ZacharyBlackwood It's really hard to tell why it's happening, possibly a config somewhere or a Django optimization which makes the response before actually saving. Putting the whole save into a single request will simplify the debug greatly. Also, best thanks on SO are upvotes ;)